# Nodejs: use eventEmitter object globally

Tags: node.js, eventemitter

Lets say I have 3 exposed functions: user, posts, articles

all of which needs to emit messages to a file called mediator where all of the events are set.

Currently I'm have trouble doing so

In the mediator file i have something like so:

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
  , pubsub = new EventEmitter();

exports.pubsub = new EventEmitter()

pubsub.on('loggedIn', function(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
});
```

and in the user, post and article functions. Something like so:

```
var mediator = require('../config/mediator')
    , _ = require('underscore')

exports.account = function(req, res) {
  var returned = _.omit(req.user._doc, 'password' )

  mediator.pubsub.emit('loggedIn', 'A User logged in');

  res.send(returned);
};
```

The emit is getting completely ignored, no error or anything. Not sure if I'm doing it right so any direction would be appreciated. The desired return is work as expected though.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You're instantiating the EventEmitter twice, so the exported one is not the one that subscribes to the event. This works:

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter
  , pubsub = new EventEmitter();

exports.pubsub = pubsub;

pubsub.on('loggedIn', function(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
});
```

Comment: Not sure how i didn't see that. Probably from frustration :). Thanks!

Comment: upvoted, how would you handle this if pub.js and sub.js were separate and needed the same eventemitter object

Comment: @PirateApp you could either pass the instance into the event emitter construction using a constructor function, or you put the event emitter in a separate file and do something like
const emitter = require('./eventEmitter.js') from both pub.js and sub.js where they'll get the same instance